# PHP Convert date using strtotime?

Tags: php, date

below is my php code.

```
<?php
    $date = "06 06 2015 6:05:00 am";
    $cdate = date("Y-m-d H:s:i",strtotime($date));
    echo $cdate;
?>
```

> Output is

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

i need to `2015-06-06 6:05:00`

Thanks

Comment: `strtotime()` can't read your date format

Comment: You want DateTime::createFromFormat() (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: use `06-06-2015 6:05:00 am` or `06/06/2015 6:05:00 am` instead of `06 06 2015 6:05:00 am`

Comment: @JoelHinz Thanks for answer please post a answer so i can accept your answer you solve my problem from comment thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `DateTime::createFromFormat()` (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Using that you can convert a string to a datetime any way you want to.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
$date = "06 06 2015 6:05:00 am";
$datetime= \DateTime::createFromFormat("m d Y h:i:s a", $date);
$cdate = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:s:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is all you plan to do with dates, continue, otherwise, consider using a good date and time class like Carbon to do more with dates and generally save yourself a lot of effort.

```
$date = "06 06 2015 6:05:00 am";
$cdate = date_create_from_format('m d Y g:i:s a', $date);
```

This allows you to specify your own format using format strings. For the entire list of format strings see: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

The resulting $cdate is a DateTime object and implements the DateTimeInterface (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) so you can use the format() method to convert the output to any format you need.

For more on format(): http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = "06 06 2015 6:05:00 am";
```

this format is not correct because first date or month but it will first year with the match of strtotime "Y-m-d H:s:i" and "06 06 2015" this is with space but it will be "-" sign.

```
$date = "2015-06-06 6:05:00 am";
$cdate = date("Y-m-d H:s:i",strtotime($date));
echo $cdate;
```

Comment: Posting code blocks without an explanation isn't helpful